# filter post_where using minutes

Tags: wordpress, filter

I'm using using a wordpress WP_Query loop that i need to filter by a certain date range.

accordingly i have set the following filter to show all posts MORE than 10 days old:

```
//Create a filter that only shows posts for a certain time frame
function restrict_posts_by_date_10( $where = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $where .= " AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')) . "'";

    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'restrict_posts_by_date_10' );
```

For testing purposes i can't wait days for the rest of the action to fire so i'd like to set this to 2 minutes. However, the following does not work

```
//Create a filter that only shows posts for a certain time frame
function restrict_posts_by_date_10( $where = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $where .= " AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 minutes')) . "'";

    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'restrict_posts_by_date_10' );
```

Any ideas would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` is a PHP function which you can read about here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

According to the manual, you could simply test with the string "now", or if you prefer, "+2 minutes".  I could find no evidence that this function takes negative integers.  I'm afraid I don't have time to test these suggestions, but it should be easy to try.